# CSS div se pega con div

Tags: html, css

tengo un problema con un trabajo que estoy realizando, quiero realizar unas figuras a base de DIVS la primera linea o se podria llamar la parte de arriba de la figura la he podido realizar el problema es que al momento de realizar la parte de abajo o la linea que esta por debajo de la primera los divs de mi primera linea se juntan con los de la primera a pesar de que les agrego un margin-top y un margin-left soy principiante en web asi que no conozco muchos trucos, les agradezco de antemano.

Este es mi HTML
[image: Esta es mi HTML]
Este mi CSS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y Asi es como se visualiza
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que requiero es que no se junte con los divs de arriba

```css
#uno {
  margin-left: 800px;
}

#dos {
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.gorra {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}

.gorra1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="uno">
    <div class="gorra"></div>
    <div class="gorra"></div>
    <div class="gorra"></div>
    <div class="gorra"></div>
    <div class="gorra"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="dos">
    <div class="gorra1"></div>
    <div class="gorra1"></div>
    <div class="gorra1"></div>
    <div class="gorra1"></div>
    <div class="gorra1"></div>
    <div class="gorra1"></div>
    <div class="gorra1"></div>
    <div class="gorra1"></div>
    <div class="gorra1"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir a tu pregunta una imagen ilustrativa de el resultado que esperas obtener?

Comment: Creo que sería de mucha utilidad que publicaras un enlace de codepen para poder ayudarte.

Comment: A no ser que lo haya copiado mal, me da que lo que se genera con el código que has puesto no coincide con la foto que has mandado

Comment: Que tal Armando antes que nada debes revisar y leer la documentación de como funciona CSS y la etiqueta "float" es la que esta dispersando mal tus divs puedes revisar el link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning y pues no hay trucos son reglas de diseño.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que estás teniendo se debe a que has usado float: left; sin seguirlo por un clear: both. Cuando usas float, los divs salen del flujo normal de la página, y su contenedor suele dejar de ocupar espacio. Si agregas un clear después de los divs con float, su contenedor volverá a ocupar el espacio que corresponde, y los márgenes se aplicarán.

Abajo ves dos ejemplos de cómo puedes implementarlo:

**Via pseudoelemento:**

```
#uno:after {
  content: ""; 
  display: block;
  clear: both; 
}
```

Esto crea un pseudo elemento a quien aplicar el clear. Tiene a su favor que no tendrás un div vacío para confundir.

**Via div vacio**

Al final de #dos, agregas:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Y en el css:

```
.clear {clear: both;}
```

```css
#uno {
  margin-left: 800px;
}
#uno:after {
  content: ""; 
  display: block;
  clear: both; 
}
#dos {
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.gorra {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}

.gorra1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
   .clear {clear: both; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="uno">
    <div class="gorra"></div>
    <div class="gorra"></div>
    <div class="gorra"></div>
    <div class="gorra"></div>
    <div class="gorra"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="dos">
    <div class="gorra1"></div>
    <div class="gorra1"></div>
    <div class="gorra1"></div>
    <div class="gorra1"></div>
    <div class="gorra1"></div>
    <div class="gorra1"></div>
    <div class="gorra1"></div>
    <div class="gorra1"></div>
    <div class="gorra1"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Para quienes miren este snippet, les recomiendo que lo vean en pantalla completa.